# Как правильно отсортировать?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите как отсортировать 32 элемента таким образом чтобы 16 были активные а остальные 16 неактивные ?

```
export const allowedNamesAll = [
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",


    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
];
```

и дальше через `map`

`allowedNamesAll.map(item => <div className="active">{item}</div>)`

Comment: Чем первые 16 элементов отличаются от 16 остальных в массиве `allowedNamesAll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то нужно вывести первые 16 элементов массива с классом "active". Для этого можно воспользоваться вторым параметром, передаваемым методом map в CallBack. Для массива - это его индекс.

В приведенном ниже примере, если индекс массива меньше 16, то элемент div выводится с классом active.

```js
const allowedNamesAll = [
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",


    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
    "name1",
];

const SortOut = () => {
   const outNames = allowedNamesAll.map((item,key) => <div key={key} className={key < 16 ? "active" : ""}>{item}</div>);
   return (<div>{outNames}</div>);
}



const domContainer = document.querySelector('#react-root');
ReactDOM.render(<SortOut/>, domContainer);
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: Только не `key < 15`, a `key < 16`